# Open browser and reload on source code changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, watch, child-process

Basically I want to open the default browser (which I handled already) and when the development folder has any changes (which I handled already) to use the browser reference to reload the url.

This is what I have done so far:

```
var open = requires('opn');
var fs = requires('fs');
var promise = open('http://localhost/my-developemnt-path/:80');
var browser;

promise.then((cp) => {
   //get a reference to the browser from the child process cp
   browser = cp;//...??
});

fs.watch('my-developemnt-path', {recursive: true}, (eventType, filename) => {
  console.log(`event type is: ${eventType}`);
  if (filename) {
    console.log(`filename provided: ${filename}`);
    browser && browser.location.reload();
  } else {
    console.log('filename not provided');
  }
});
```

So how do I get the browser reference out of the child-process and how can I use it to force a reload?

**CLARIFICATIONS**

1. I am not using any Express or other particular application. Just a common web app I am running on Apache.
2. I am using nodejs just to open a browser window and monitor files changes under the working dir.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/reload ?

Comment: @AlexBlex could be reload. I tried t but when I change the source code in a sub folder the page is not reloading though the console says something like `Server restarted  at 15:47:29`. I launched with `reload -n my.local.com -p 81 -b`. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer then?

Comment: @AlexBlex pupeteer is using its own Chromium browser. I want to use my browser instance, loading files trough my Apache web server. reload was promising but it is not refreshing the page :(

Comment: I don't think an abstract "default browser" has a system level API to reload a page by process id. You need to compromise somewhere. `reload` requires `/reload/reload.js` in your html to do the job. `puppeteer` uses a specific browser. The other options you have is a selenium web driver, or do not reload the page but reload the whole browser. The most expensive approach is to write a browser extension to do expose such API.

Comment: Give a try to https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync. It works similarly to `reload`, but injects the client-side javascript automatically.

Comment: @AlexBlex Ohhh! Isn't reload injecting automatically the client code??

Comment: No: https://www.npmjs.com/package/reload#how-does-it-work. `browser-sync` does it because it is a proxy, but `reload` just starts an express app to serve the client-side script. It is your responsibility to ensure the page has the `<script>` tag to load it. The docs are quite explicit about it: "*All you have to do is include the reload script and have it be on every page of your project*"

Comment: @AlexBlex I am using the second way, the command line. I m nit having an express application.

Comment: Dear @bluehipy, please read and comprehend at least the readme page of the project. The cli option **does** start the express server for you: "*2. As a command line tool which starts its own Express application to monitor the file you're editing for changes and to serve reload-client.js to the browser.*"

Comment: @AlexBlex you are right, I didn't notice that note :(